# Atualizar a Pagina( windows) durante o Click do Botão, o Spinner para de funcionar no WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, spinners, usercontrol

Estou fazendo uma aplicação WPF em c#, que quando eu clico no botão consultar no banco. Ele começa a girar um "Spinner" que esta dentro do UserControl;

```
 private void BtnBusca_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    MessageControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
    FuncaoBuscabanco(TbCampoBusca.Text);
    MessageControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Ao clicar no Botão, ele não pare de rodar e continue a fazer minha busca no banco de dados.